# Problems by embedding php vars into json

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have this json code:

```
    $dataB = <<<DATA
{


    "actualArrivalDateTime":"2021-09-07T10:00", 
    "containerNumber:" "000",
    "shipmentNumber": aaaa1, 
    "containerSequence":3,  
    "placeOfArrival": {
        "pointSequence": 2
                        }
                        
    
} 
DATA;
```

I want to pass php var to containerNumber but doesn't work .
For example, if i assign:

```
<? $contnr = "001"; ?>
```

then i tried to do this:

```
    $dataB = <<<DATA
{


    "actualArrivalDateTime":"2021-09-07T10:00", 
    "containerNumber:" ".$var.",
    "shipmentNumber": aaaa1, 
    "containerSequence":3,  
    "placeOfArrival": {
        "pointSequence": 2
                        }
                        
    
} 
DATA;
```

but dowsn't work... it says that the containerNumber is not valid... but if i write the containerNumber, not as variable, it works.
Any help?

Comment: Normally, you would convert your JSON string into a PHP array (or object) using `json_decode`, modify it, then convert it back to a JSON string using `json_encode`.

Comment: can you pls helpme with an example?

Comment: `".$var."` should be `"$var"`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/h4dLNtbMyhbdrW17 Please do some debugging before you ask a question. A simple `echo $dataB` whould show you the problem.

Comment: i tried to do as you said, and works when you write the json with echo $dataB. But when i pass this json to a server that receives these value it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would convert your JSON string into a PHP array (or object) using `json_decode`, modify it, then convert it back to a JSON string using `json_encode`.

Your JSON string in the question is invalid. Use a tool such as this https://jsonlint.com/ to validate it.

Wrong placement of colon in `"containerNumber:"` and unquoted string `aaaa1`

> ```
> {
>     "actualArrivalDateTime":"2021-09-07T10:00", 
>     "containerNumber:" "000",
>     "shipmentNumber": aaaa1, 
>     "containerSequence":3,  
>     "placeOfArrival": {
>         "pointSequence": 2
>     }
> }
> ```

It should be something like this,

```
{
    "actualArrivalDateTime": "2021-09-07T10:00",
    "containerNumber": "000",
    "shipmentNumber": "aaaa1",
    "containerSequence": 3,
    "placeOfArrival": {
        "pointSequence": 2
    }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8294e0b699bf560618dfa44efe9f09b892ecc31

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{
    "actualArrivalDateTime": "2021-09-07T10:00",
    "containerNumber": "000",
    "shipmentNumber": "aaaa1",
    "containerSequence": 3,
    "placeOfArrival": {
        "pointSequence": 2
    }
}';

// Convert it to an object
$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);

// Now change it
$jsonObject->containerNumber = '001';

// Convert it back to a JSON string. 
echo json_encode($jsonObject);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help.
Do you know how can i check if the the server response is 200 or not?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you using to make the request? AJAX, CURL, Guzzle? Might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: i used curl: curl_setopt($curlB, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataB);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curlB, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curlB, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: can i contact you via msgs? I can explain better... here i cannot post a new question or answer, i only can write as comment :(

Comment: Sorry, don't have time right now, but I'd start here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/11797680/296555. Also, don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it helped you out. Thanks.