# Check if url is exist or not

Tags: php

I've website where visitor would submit links so i would like of the posted url is exist or not so i've been using the following function

```
<?PHP
        function url_exist($url){
        $c=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);
        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1);
        if(!curl_exec($c)){
        return false;
        }else{
        return true;
        }}

    $ur = "http://www.google.com"; // example

    if(url_exist($url)){
    echo "yea valid";
    }else{
    echo "not valid";
    }
?>
```

but my website become so slow and something not even loading at the step of checking if valid or not valid url so i wonder if there any idea else can do the same without loading too much on my hosting server as the above function !! ~ any help

Comment: This is a repost, also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum without using CURL ! this is awesome ~ thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if an URL exists in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code, hope it will work.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/file.jpg';
$file_header = @get_headers($url);
if($file_header[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $is_exists = false;
}
else {
    $is_exists = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using this code may work

```
$headers = @get_headers($url);
if(strpos($headers[0],'200')===false)return false;
```

So if a url returns anything other than code 200, you will know that url is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'http://google.com/';

if( get_headers($url) )
    echo "$url exists";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using example from [link](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/83076/if-url-exists) in the accepted answer:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if ($handle !== false) {
   echo 'Exists';
} else {
   echo "Doesn't";
}
```

Reproducing here in case external resource becomes unavailable in the future.