# redirect all invalid urls to url.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to create a rule in `.htaccess` if the page or folder does not exist redirect to url.php

Comment: If you want to use PHP only, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `ErrorDocument`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /url.php
```

you can also use  for 403,500 etc

```
ErrorDocument 403 /url.php
ErrorDocument 500 /url.php
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^404.php$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to your root .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /url.php
```