# Php redirect to variable if existent

Tags: php, redirect

Afternoon! I am trying to check if a URL received from a post variable exists and if it does send the user there. If not redirect elsewhere... I wrote this but for some reason Is not working,

Any ideas?
Cheers

```
<?php>
$file = $_POST["code"];
$file_headers =                   
@get_headers('http://example.co.uk/' $file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
/* does not exist
header('Location: http://example.co.uk/?exists=false');
echo $file 'not found';
}
else {
/* exists
header('Location: http://example.co.uk/' $file);
echo $file 'found';
};
?>
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php

Comment: Please post code that is without syntax errors unless you ask about the error message itself. Thank you for choosing flying with us.

Answer (score 4):

You are using comments wrong. It is `//` and **not** `/*` when doing a one line comment.

As you can see from the markdown display, the whole end of your code is currently *commented out* and your script will have errors.

Comment: May be worth mentioning how to use multiline `/* */` properly

Answer (score 0):

Try do it that way:

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```