# PHP get headers does not work with -

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the output of URL headers and it works great with a subdomain example

```
subdomain.example.com
```

I will get the normal message HTTP 200 ok etc, but if the subdomain has `-` in it nothing is displayed in the headers.

`-test.tumblr.com` or `test-.tumblr.com`

Is there a better way of doing this? My example code is below.

```
$url = "http://-test.tumblr.com";
$url_headers = @get_headers($url);
$urlheader = $url_headers[0];
echo $urlheader;
```

If it cannot be done with checking the headers how else would I go about seeing if the page exists. I have tried using curl but it does the same.

Thanks

Comment: Is `-subdomain` or `subdomain-` valid at all?

Comment: Yes but that isn't the exact URL I'm testing. I didn't want to put it up and be marked as spam.

Comment: Those are not valid as hostnames cannot start or end with a hyphen. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname

Comment: I have update my question with a test URL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you un-supress the warning from get_headers do you get the warning that you can only use get_headers on urls?

```
Warning: get_headers(): This function may only be used against URLs
```

try adding http:// in front of the subdomain. I added a subdomain test-.myserver.loc to my hosts file and was able to get the headers.

```
$url = 'http://test-.myserver.loc';
print_r(get_headers($url))
```

https://www.php.net/get_headers

Comment: the address also has to resolve... before I added it to my hosts file, I go this error:
    Warning: get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: I added a comment to my question that shows the url as a example I'm trying to get. Thanks

Comment: I basically want to see if the page exist/real using the url in my comments.

Comment: var_dump(gethostbynamel('http://-blue--crush-.tumblr.com')); will return false if doesn't exist
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php

Comment: I'm getting false on real pages and non real pages.

Comment: I think you are on the right track... have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php

Comment: I tried curl already it won't fetch anything when `-` is at the end or beginning of the sub domain. I'm actively looking for a solution. Thanks