# redirect based on the keyword the user entered

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a page where the user can enter what he is selling and be redirected to that page. I know the mysql `LIKE '%%' function` but I am not using database. If the case matches, I just would like to redirect to that page. How is that possible? whether it is javascript or php?

**For examples:** if the user enters "laptop" then he/she will be redirected to laptop.php(I have the pages). How can I do that?

The form structure:

```
 <form class="sellcont" action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="selling" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="myButton">
 </form>


 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $sell = $_POST['selling'];
 if(!empty($_POST['selling'])){

//This is where I am lost. 

}


 }
```

Comment: But  how can you restrict the user or you will create the page like laptop.php... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After Comments**

You use php `header` to redirect and check the input ($_POST['selling']) with `in_array` if its a good input.

```
$goodinput = array("laptop", "pc", "mac", "cellphone");

if(!empty($_POST['selling'])){

    if (in_array($_POST['selling'],$goodinput)){ //checks if user input is a  good input

       header('Location: http://www.yoururl.com/'.$_POST['selling'].'php');
       exit();

    } else {

       header('Location: http://www.yoururl.com/wedonthavethatpage.php');
       exit();

    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

- Instead of creating individual pages e.g.: `laptop.php` you store similar values in a database and create dynamic pages.

Comment: I don't think you got my point. I know the header function but my question is that how do I check for what the user entered and then redirect. using header ofcourse

Comment: @amdvb `$_POST['selling']` holds what the user has typed in. if you wan't to know what they typed in you just have to check `$_POST['selling']`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: oh okay but regarding error 404. is there a better way for this?

Comment: @amdvb it would be best that you have a list of all your pages and store it in an array. Then process `$_POST['selling']` if its in the array, if its not you send the user to a page that says, `sorry. we don't have that`. OR you could let users choose what is allowed, maybe inside a dropdown menu instead of your users typing it.

Comment: I mage suggestions but which one do you want?

Comment: I already have auto complete for suggestion. But I didn't like using select box. I also have the pages created already just need to redirect.

Comment: @amdvb ahh. i see. then simply store your accepted inputs in an array then use `if statement` with `in_array` to check if the value is accepted else redirect to a friendlier page than a `404 error` page

Comment: @amdvb I editted my answer. If you find it helpful check it so that others will know that your question has been answered. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

PHP code should be like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $sell = $_POST['selling'];
 if(!empty($_POST['selling'])){
     header('location: ./'.$_POST['selling'].'.php');   
 }
 else {
     header('location: ./index.php');  //index.php is PHP files on which user enter selling item
  }  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the code in this answer:

[How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php)

to see if the what the user typed in is available. If so, do the redirect, if not, send it to an alternate page.

E.g.

```
if(!empty($_POST['selling'])){
    $file = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$_POST['selling'].'.php';
    $file_headers = @get_headers($file);
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        $exists = false;
    }
    else {
        $exists = true;
    }

    if ($exists) {
        header(sprintf('Location: %s', $file);
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/other_page.php');
    }
    exit();
}
```