# Display 404 error jquery

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404

I have this php-jquery code

```
<?php
//a php code determines value of the variable $url
echo "<script>
$('#main').html('Loading...'); 
$('#main').load('".$url."');
</script>";
?>
```

But, when the path indicated in $url doesn't exist, the content of #main remains stuck to "Loading..." and it doesn't display a 404 error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your url is not valid (not found)

Comment: Maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough, I apologize for that. $url is determined dynamically, and could be (not always) non-existent. In this case, I'd like to display a custom message.

Comment: Ajax `error: function(jqXHR, exception) {if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
alert("Requested page not found. [404]");//show error}}`

Comment: You can check if url not exist and then show "error page".
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why "Loading" is stuck there is because [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is an ajax  call and although returns a 400 response, does not actually reload the page.

What you can do is make use of [jQuery load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) callback function like

```
$("...").load("yourURL", function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      //do something here, like redirect the page for example
   }
});
```