# check the validity of a url in php

Tags: php, url

Is there a way to find if ad url is valid

I tried this code

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
   echo 'Not a valid URL';
}
else
   echo 'Ok';
```

but if I try with `http://www.gsrgrs.grsgsrg`, for example, the result is ok.

**Edit:** The goal is to see if there's a live website there.

Comment: Isn't it a valid url?

Comment: This is because is a valid url.

Comment: Define "valid". Valid format, or valid in the sense that there's a live website there, responding to requests?

Comment: Sorry, for valid URL I suppose valid in the sense that there's a live website there

Comment: Then try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php

Comment: I tried it before but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gsrgrs.grsgsrg is a perfectly valid URL, therefore the test result is correct.

If your intent is to discover whether a URL points to a valid resource instead, you should employ cURL or a similar library to attempt a fetch operation, and test for the protocol response code, for example with:

```
$http = curl_init($url);
$result = curl_exec($http);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($http);
if($http_status == 200)
    echo 'Ooooh, we got a 200 OK response from the webserver!';
else
    echo 'Meh, failed with '.$http_status.' :(';
```

Comment: Sorry, for valid URL I suppose valid in the sense that there's a live website there

Comment: Why bother? Anyway you'd probably have to use spiders to crawl the sites and see if they hit anything.