# validate URL by FILTER_VALIDATE_URL

Tags: php, validation

I am validating URL by `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` function.

```
$url_1 = "http://example.com";
$url_2 = "http://http://example.com";

if (filter_var($url_1, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo "URL is valid";
}
else {
    echo "URL is invalid";
}
```

It's giving me valid URL message in `$url_1` and `$url_2`. It shouldn't be like that. second URL is not valid.
What's the correct way to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: May be worth a read: *Validates value as URL (according to » http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396)*

Comment: Because the second url ***is*** technically valid, the domain name has to be in the RFC1037 format, which is a file access protocol. Therefore it has to allow for usernames, passwords and path specifiers: `http://foo:bar@somesite.org` is valid, and so if there were a user `http`, a `//` containing password should be valid, too: `https://http://myPass@foo.bar` has to be valid, too. Does it make sense? No, but the URL is parseable, so technically, it's valid

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs on [validation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` will validate the URL to the [RFC 2396 standards](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396).

There's also been discussion on [examples that still pass the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#107300).

This means you can use the filter to do *some* validation, but you can't depend on it solely if you need a 100% valid URL as certain conditions would still satisfy the RFC, plus a valid URL could still return a `404`.

Your best approach to test a valid URL is to actually test the URL itself after validating it [as per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2280413/1188035)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function checkdnsrr() to check DNS records corresponding to a given Internet host name or IP address :

```
$url = "wrong_url.com";
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && checkdnsrr(($url),"A")) {
    echo "URL is valid";
}
else {
    echo "URL is invalid";
}
```

Comment: @RonakPatel: `checkdnsrr` takes a host name not a URL.

Comment: @MagicProg.fr: `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` needs a URL with protocol/scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It's been filed as a bug before:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64173

and

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65141

but it's conform the RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

```
Quick BNF evaluation

absoluteURI
    scheme http
    :
    hier_part
        net_path
            //
            authority
                server
                    hostport http:

            abs_path
                /
                segment
                segment /www.google.com
```

You can use other, stricter functions if you like: https://github.com/franksrevenge/StrictUrlValidator