# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_URL TLD not required

Tags: php, validation

The problem I find using `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` is that it returns true when `$url = "http://x";`

No TLD is required. How I can solve this so a TLD is required?

Comment: [We actually had another question about this today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26489341/1188035). Check out all the links in there for additional strategies to fully validate a URL. [Something like this library could help you](https://github.com/franksrevenge/StrictUrlValidator)

Comment: urls not necessarily need TLD for beeing valid.
ie. 

    http://localhost/myproject/index.php

Comment: you can use regular expression. See here:
http://www.regexr.com/38vdq

Answer (score 1):

For TLD validation you need library that operates with [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). Here are two diffent solutions for you.

First is [TLDDatabase](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDDatabase), technicaly it's only actual database of TLDs.

```
$store = new LayerShifter\TLDDatabase\Store();

$store->isICCAN('com'); // returns true
$store->isICCAN('co.uk'); // returns true
$store->isICCAN('example'); // returns false
```

If you need more intelligent solution, I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract). It's domain parser that you can use as validator.

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();
$extract->setExtractionMode(Extract::MODE_ALLOW_ICCAN);

# For domain 'shop.github.com'

$result = $extract->parse('shop.github.com');
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'github.com'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'com'    

# For domain 'shop.github.co.uk'

$result = $extract->parse('http://shop.github.co.uk');
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'github.co.uk'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'co.uk'    

# For domain 'example.example'

$result = $extract->parse('https://example.example');
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return NULL
$result->getSuffix(); // will return NULL

# For domain 'localhost'

$result = $extract->parse('localhost');
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return NULL
$result->getSuffix(); // will return NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Any URI starting with a scheme, like `http://`, and containing valid URI characters after that **is valid** as per the official URI specification in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.1):

> Each URI begins with a scheme name, as defined in Section 3.1, that refers to a specification for assigning identifiers within that scheme.  As such, the URI syntax is a federated and extensible naming system wherein each scheme's specification may further restrict the syntax and semantics of identifiers using that scheme.

What FILTER_VALIDATE_URL does is correct.

`http://localhost` or `http://x` are perfectly valid URIs.

If you really want to require and validate the TLD, then you have to use a white list, containing all the valid TLDs. Because each TLD differs on what counts as a subdomain, second level domain, etc.
There are top level domains, second level domains, and subdomains. Technically speaking, everything except the TLD is a subdomain.

You find a maintained list of TLDs here:

- https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat
- https://publicsuffix.org/

For a PHP implementation (list parser):

- http://toby.ink/blog/2007/07/19/php-domain-class/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917859/1163786

From my perspective, this problem can't be solved by a "regexp" or "number of dots in hostname scan".
One exception: if the usage scope of the validator is limited to only a few known urls, then you might solve this problem using these strategies.

Interesting is the MX record check suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14688913/1163786

Referencing

- [Why does the Symfony2 URL validator skip the TLD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623208/why-does-the-symfony2-url-validator-skip-the-tld)
- [Get the subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url)