# How to check image exists on another server or not?

Tags: php

How i will check that a particular image with given path exists on another server or not? I have the following code in which i used file get contents but that is taking so long time and due to that sometimes jquery stops working.

```
function is_file_url_exists($url) 
{
    if (@file_get_contents($url, 0, NULL, 0, 1)) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use php bbuiltin function file_exists?

```
if (file_exists($url)) {   
   return 1;                     
}
else
   return 0;
```

Or You can also use:

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   $exists = false;
}
else {
   $exists = true;
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: This works for checking on same server..i dont think this will work for different server..

Comment: Why do you think so, TECHNOMAN?

Comment: bcoz i did testing of your code and that did not run..

Comment: Also the solution given on this page is also not working.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php ....it is always giving value 1