# How can I check if a URL exists via Laravel?

Tags: php, url, laravel

I did look at this answer:

[How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)

However, I was wondering if a method exists in Laravel that can check if a URL exists (not 404) or not?

Comment: Do you want to check an an external url or a route inside of laravel?

Comment: @DouglasDC3: I wasn't aware there was a difference. I'd like to check an external url.

Comment: The best way is described in the other post you added.

Comment: @DouglasDC3: So you're saying there's no way to do this via Laravel?

Comment: As far as I know not. I have looked in to it and laravel doesn't provide this kind of functionality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you want to check if a there's a route matching a certain URL.

```
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
$request = Request::create('the/url/you/want/to/check');
try {
    $routes->match($request);
    // route exists
}
catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e){
    // route doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check an external URL via Laravel?

Comment: The OP mentioned he wants to check an external URL. He didn't say a route within the app.

Comment: for some reason I am not getting the ```NotFoundHttpException``` even when the route does not exists. I instead get a route object with uri: `{fallbackPlaceholder}`. Any ideas?

Comment: @ThembaClarenceMalungani Like this:

```
protected function routeExists(string $url): bool
{
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    $request = Request::create($url);

    return (bool) $routes->match($request)->getName();
}

$this->routeExists($this->request->fullUrl())
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned you want to check an external URL (eg. `https://google.com`), not a route within the app , you can use use the `Http` facade in Laravel as such (https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-client):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('https://google.com');

if( $response->successful() ) {
    // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not particular laravel function, but you can make a try on this

```
 function urlExists($url = NULL)
    {
        if ($url == NULL) return false;
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) ? true : false;        
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
function checkRoute($route) {
    $routes = \Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes();
    foreach($routes as $r){
        if($r->getUri() == $route){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for route parameters - using the `$routes->match()` would fix that.