# How can you check if a laravel route can be accessed before calling it

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a laravel 4.2 app. And I have filters on many of the routes.

I am trying to display navigation and I would like to be able to check that a link can be accessed before displaying it.

I can't see a way to check that a routes before filters would pass given a URL.

Is this possible?

I have tried to get the route using the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854247/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-laravel)

But calling `callRouteBefore()` on it doesn't seem to give the expected results. I think it is due to the session not being right.

Comment: And what do you want to do if a route _can’t_ be accessed?

Comment: Either hide the link or grey it out with a message that access is not sufficient.

Comment: You’re better off doing this through user permissions. Map which pages a user can access, and then when generating your menu do a permission check and apply the appropriate styling.