# Laravel check if route for given url exists inside routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

By providing a URL I would like to know if there's any way to determine if the URL exists in my Laravel application (in comparison to "[How can I check if a URL exists via Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854247/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-laravel)" which wants to check an external URL)?

I tried this but it always tells me the URL doesn't match:

```
$routes = \Route::getRoutes();
$request = \Request::create('/exists');
try {
    $routes->match($request);
    // route exists
} catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e){
    // route doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: can you echo `$request`?

Comment: Yes, it delivers me the Request headers: `GET /exists HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Host: localhost User-Agent: Symfony/3.X`

Comment: this seems to be correct, are you sure the route already exists? could you dump the `$routes` ?

Answer (score 10):

simply use if Route::has('example')

Answer (score 5):

In one of my Laravel application, I achieved it by doing the following

```
private function getRouteSlugs()
{
    $slugs  = [];
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();

    foreach ($routes as $route)
    {
        $parts = explode('/', $route->uri());
        foreach ($parts as $part)
        {
            $slug    = trim($part, '{}?');
            $slugs[] = $slug;
        }
    }

    return array_unique($slugs);
}
```

This function would help to get all the slugs that are registered within Laravel and then with a simple `in_array` you can check if that slug has been reserved.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you can extend the following function

```
private function getRouteSlugs()
{
    $slugs  = [];
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();

    foreach ($routes as $route)
    {
        $slugs[] = $route->uri();
    }

    return array_unique($slugs);
}
```

That will get you an array of items as such:

```
0 => "dashboard/news"
1 => "dashboard/post/news"
2 => "dashboard/post/news/{id}"
3 => "dashboard/post/news"
```

It should be easy enough from here to compare.

Comment: I get the exception `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getPath()` if I use it with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`?

Comment: Updated for Laravel 5.4 compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It shows me the slugs now, but I have routes which are more complicated like `/foo/{id}-{name}` or `/{foo}/{bar}-{foobar}` or `/{foo}?param={bar}&param2={bar2}` etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Well the code above will get you the routes that are defined in your Routes file. I am exploding it and doing some manipulation to get the slug but you can just check for an instance of $route->uri instead. It should be easy enough to modify the code above a bit to get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

`Route::has('route_name')` check if the route exists (on routes files).

Example: test some app routes

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Users\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Tests\TestCase;

class RouteTest extends TestCase
{
    private $routes = [
        'home',
        'users.index',
        'employees.index',
        'logs.index',
    ];


    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // Put an admin on session
        $adminUser = User::getFirstAdmin();
        $this->actingAs($adminUser);
    }

    public function testRoutes()
    {
        foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
            $this->assertTrue(Route::has($route));

            $response = $this->get(route($route));
            $response->assertStatus(200);
        }
    }
}
```

> Edition

The fast way, check with ***tinker*** typing on the terminal:

```
php artisan tinker
```

then:

```
Route::has('your_route')
```

or

```
route('your_route')
```