# Check if URL exists - Not Working with php get_headers

Tags: php

I need to determine if a URL exits. I ran across this post.

[How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)

```
$file = 'http://godaddy';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') 
{
    $exists = false;
}
else 
{
    $exists = true;
}
```

And implemented this code and when I tested it as a user who forgot to put in the .com it comes back with true. Which isn't correct because if you go to http://godaddy there is no website.

I tried validating the $file before hand but

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

views http://godaddy as a valid url.

Any idea how to handle this sort of input?

```
var_dump($file_headers)= array(8) {
    [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    [1]=> string(13) "Server: nginx"
    [2]=> string(35) "Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 14:23:07 GMT"
    [3]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html"
    [4]=> string(17) "Connection: close"
    [5]=> string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding"
    [6]=> string(38) "Expires: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 14:23:06 GMT"
    [7]=> string(23) "Cache-Control: no-cache"
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($file_headers)`. you're not going to get an http error code is an http request couldn't be performed in the first place. `http://godaddy` WOULD be a valid url **IF** you had a host named `godaddy` in whatever your local DNS zone is.

Comment: Your DNS host (ISP or such) may be presenting you with a default error/search page for non-existing domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `@` character. in this way you can see the direct error. I think the error masking  cannot permit the correct reading of the response of the `get_header`