# Block href to specific domains with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a php website hosted in a LAMP environment.
Many pages contain references to `somedomain.com` (such as images src). If somedomain.com should become unreachable, my site would go to timeout (and error 500).
Is there a way to block all somedomain.com request of my pages, let's say redirecting them to localhost using .htaccess?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do this with a `.htaccess` file. But in php it's quite easy. Just request headers of `somedomain.com` and use if / else statement on 404 returned. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php) question for more info.

Comment: Its imposible because client(browser) call somedomain.com when load these images. Your .htaccess can manage connections only for yours server. This problem have solution - use proxy script on your server.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because these resources are loaded by browser, e.g. for image:

```
<img src="somedomain.com/img/someimg.png" />
```

A possible way is to proxify these resources with a PHP script :

```
 <img src="myproxy.php?url=http://somedomain.com/img/someimg.png" />
```

Which it's looks like :

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents(@$_GET['url']);

/*
 * There is an error
 */
if (!$content) {
    $content = file_get_contents('alternate_local_img.png');
} 

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $content;
```

It's can be improved with extension/mime type detection.