# How to validate html url as audio url

Tags: php, html

How to validate this url us audio url

```
<input type="url" id="audio" name="audio" value="http://localhost/audio/warna.mp3">
```

anyone one can enter `http://fake.com/audio.mp3` OR http://real.com/fake.mp3 OR http://real.com
html5 input type only check url but not audio url

this is link only confirm that url exist or not but don't validate that this url is **audio url** 
[How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)
Please anyone guide me to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

refer to [How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)
at first you should check the file extension against audio file formats
the next step is to use the example above to check is the url exists.

Comment: can u elaborate the answer