# Go to other link if a web page is not available in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any option in HTML or JavaScript for when a user clicks on a link, if that link is available then done, if not then goes on another link.

Here is part of my code:

```
<div id="sidebar-collapse" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/returns"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Returns</a></li>
    <li  class="active"><a href="/pay_reco" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Payment Recouncillation </a></li>
    <li ><a href="/pay_get" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Payment Get </a></li>
    <li><a href="/import"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Import </a></li>
    <li>

<!-- Here I want to add  Two link in a href tag if first link does not 

available (web page not available) then it go to another link
        <!-- <object data="http:/127.0.0.1:9004" type="href" > -->
        <a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:9001">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
             ComPare
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:9000"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Portal </a></li>
```

Comment: your li has no parent ul?also what do you mean by `Click on a link, if that link is available then done If not then goes on another link.`

Comment: @guradio ya just put part of code and that have ul , i want if web webpage is not available on first link then it go to open second link

Comment: Why would you put invalid links to your own site in a document?

Comment: Could you add some comments in your *code* to maybe explain how the code you posted is at all relevant to the question you asked

Comment: @JaromandaX I am just trying, If it is possible then How ? if not then Dont worry

Comment: @user - almost anything is possible

Comment: @JaromandaX ya I am agree with You. I hope we found the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php

Comment: @www139 Sory bro but that is using php, I want do it by using HTML or Javascript

Comment: Ok :) You may consider using PHP, it will be much easier like this. Another option might be to load in the url behind the scenes in an iframe and see if it loads with JavaScript. That would be very wasteful though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Update your HTML code like below.

```
<a id="selector" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
             ComPare
</a>
```

Step 2: After update your HTML, handle click event with jQuery and send ajax request, if response ok, go link 1, or another case you route to user another url.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#selector', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:9001",    
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
               if(xhr.status == 200) window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:9001";
               else window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:9004";
            } 
        });
    })
})
```

I created little jQuery plugin for this case on [here](https://github.com/frknbasaran/another)

With **AnotherJS**:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:9001" data-another="http://127.0.0.1:9004">Link Text</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $('a').another();
})
```

That's all! :)