# recursive PHP function return Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

i'm working on a small DOM project, to get dynamic links and static links. but my function take a lot of time to be executed and return an error as you can see

```
allowed memory size of bytes exhausted
```

this is my PHP code:

```
public $domain_name = 'www.example.com'; 
public function dynamic_url2($url = "http://www.example.com"){
    $pages = array();
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $page){
        if(valid_url($page->href)){
            $parse_page = parse_url($page->href);
            if($parse_page['host'] == $this->domain_name){
                if(!in_array($page->href, $pages)){
                    $pages[] = $page->href;
                    if(array_key_exists('query', $parse_page))
                        echo 'contain dynamic parameters : '. $page->href.'<br>';
                    else
                        echo 'not dynamic : '. $page->href.'<br>';
                }
                return $this->dynamic_url2($page->href);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is my function correct ? how can i optimize it ?

thanks

Comment: i want to check all the website links ( my function is like a spider ) i'm starting from the index page ( i wan't to check all website links ) for example 
from the index page i open page2 and i open all the links and i go to page3 and i open all the links .. ( i want to check all the website links )

Comment: I see.  So you are experiencing infinite recursion because you are not passing the `$pages` data to the next function call -- you are only passing the new url.  So if you "crawl" two pages that refer to each other -- bonk -- you are stuck in an indefinite loop.  You must make `$pages` available to subsequent calls.

Comment: how can i do it can you give me an example please 
thanks brother

Comment: Some people post their ideas straight away.  I don't post an answer until I have tested it first.  This is why I am slow to answer and I rarely enjoy the spoils of quick answer upvotes.  I'll set up a test for myself and if you aren't already helped, I'll post something.

Comment: ok thank you so much ;)

Comment: I see a lot wrong with this. You're not keeping track of pages you've visited and you're not converting relative urls to absolute. Also simple-html-dom will run out of memory quickly even without infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some minor adjustments that I made while testing, you only need to make `$pages` modifiable (via `&$pages` in the function declaration) and pass the `$pages` array with every recursive call.

```
public $domain_name = 'https://www.example.html'; 
public function dynamic_url2($url, &$pages = []){
    //echo "<div>Crawling $url</div>";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // for malformed html warning suppression
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));  // this doesn't account for relative urls
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($xpath->query("//a") as $a) {
        $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
        //echo "<div>Found $href @ $url</div>";
        if (valid_url($href)) {
            $parsed = parse_url($href);
            if ($parsed['host'] == $this->domain_name && !in_array($href, $pages)) {
                $pages[] = $href;
                //echo "<div>$href is " , (array_key_exists('query', $parsed) ? '' : 'not ') , 'dynamic</div>';
                $this->dynamic_url2($href, $pages);
            } else {
                //echo "<div>Ignored url: $href</div>";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "<div>Invalid url: $href</div>";
        }
    }
    return $pages;    
}
var_export($this->dynamic_url2($this->domain_name));
```

Comment: Is `valid_url` Drupal's function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/valid_url/7.x ?  I suppose there should also be a check that the headers of new urls give a good response so that my `$dom->load()` call doesn't bark.  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2280413/2943403)

Comment: Okay, I just spent far too long in the rabbit hole while correcting relative and absolute paths based on the parent url using regex and such.  I'm not going to do that -- it goes way too far for this question.  Suffice to say, you can eliminate infinite recursion by implementing the '&$pages` technique that I have described.  I'm done.