# PHP check if file exists on my server, based on a full URL

Tags: php

I have an app that generates invoices in the form of PDF files stored in a directory on my server. Before mailing out this invoices I'd like to make sure that the URL (not server path) which I store in my DB does indeed point to a valid PDF file.

Something could have gone wrong that wrote a value to that field in the db, but for example the filename is missing; meaning the file is not in the specified directory.

AFAIK file_exists just checks server paths but not URL's.

I could always store the server path too, or assemble it, but I'm wondering if i can do this check based on a full http url ending with a filename?

EDIT: yeah CURL occurred to me too but doesn't that seem a bit heavy for such a simple task? Perhaps I should just store the server path too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could validate the request by opening the URL [using PHP+cURL as described here](http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/03/23/to-validate-if-an-url-exists-use-php-curl/) and check the HTTP status code that's returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$file = 'http://mysite.co.za/files/invoice.pdf';
$file_exists = (@fopen($file, "r")) ? true : false;
```

Worked for me when trying to check if an image exists on the URL

Answer (score -2):

You can use function **file_get_contents()** or **fopen()**