# Getting the list of files over FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I want to print the list of files and only files from an FTP server, here is what I could accomplish.

```
<?php
    $ftp_server = "my ftp server";
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $ftp_user_name = "ftp username";
    $ftp_user_pass = "ftp password";
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($contents) ; $i++)
        echo "<li>" . substr($contents[$i],1) . "</li>";
    ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

but this prints the names of files and folders. How can I just print the names of files (files may not have extensions!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Options:

1) you can use `ftp_rawlist` instead of `ftp_nlist` to get the full listing for the file/directory, which should indicate whether it's a directory.  However, the format of that listing will depend on the operating system of the ftp server.  For example, on a unix/linux system the raw listing might look something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 jm72 jm72  4096 Nov  2 16:39 myDir
-rw-rw-r--  1 jm72 jm72   257 Nov  2 16:39 myFile
```

where the "d" in the first column will tell you it's a directory.  Not sure what it would look like on a Windows server.

2) for each file name you return, try to CD into it.  If you can, it's a directory!

```
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, substr($contents[$i],1)) {
  //it's a directory, don't include it in your list
  ftp_cdup($conn_id) //don't forget to go back up to the directory you started in!
}
```

Comment: @JacobM: it worked but gave the following error: (Warning: ftp_chdir() [function.ftp-chdir]: /index.php: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Contact_Keeper\copyftp.php) on line 14 for each file that it found ... and for the structure it should be ftp_chdir($ftp_stream,$directory) (got it from the dreamweaver)

Comment: @RobertPitt: Yes, that's more readable and fits the OP's need better.  I just wanted to make my example short!

Comment: @RobertPitt: I just need the files in a specific folder.

Comment: @JacobM: I solved the error by adding error_reporting(0); at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @sikas: if the warning is a problem, you can change `ftp_chdir` to `@ftp_chdir` to suppress the warning, but be aware that will also suppress legitimate errors (for example, the network has gone down).

Comment: Sorry, but I think I have a better solution as my way does not require changing directory

Answer (score 6):

Here is a script that will do it for you, courtesy of a poster on [ftp_nlist (PHP Docs)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php):

```
<?php

//identify directories

function ftp_is_dir($dir) {
  global $ftp_connect;
  if (@ftp_chdir($ftp_connect, $dir)) {
       ftp_chdir($ftp_connect, '..');
       return true;
  } else {
       return false;
  }
}
$ftp_nlist = ftp_nlist($ftp_connect, ".");

//alphabetical sorting

sort($ftp_nlist);
foreach ($ftp_nlist as $v) {

//1. ftp_is_dir() is true => directory
  if (ftp_is_dir($v)) {

//output as [ directory ]
      echo "[ " . $v . " ]<br />\n";
  }
}
foreach ($ftp_nlist as $v) {

//2. ftp_is_dir() is false => file
  if (!ftp_is_dir($v)) {

//output as file
      echo "" . $v . "<br />\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me but I would recommend silencing the ftp_chdir with @ftp_chdir in the function's if because it will spit out warnings when trying to enter files.

Comment: Your code not working for me. the function always returns false. It thinks all are files not directory!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `ftp_mdtm()` function.  This always returns an error (-1) when it fails which would indicate a directory since this function doesn't work for directories.  The one caveat is that it doesn't work on some systems (the manual doesn't state which ones), so you'd need to test if it worked first.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the ftp_rawlist like so:

```
$rawfiles = ftp_rawlist($conn, true); //true being for recursive

foreach ($rawfiles as $rawfile)
{
    $info = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $rawfile, 9);
    if($info[0]{0} == 'd')
    {
        //Directory
    }else
    {
        //File
        $size = byteconvert($info[4]);
        $chmod = chmodnum($info[0]);
        $date = strtotime($info[6] . ' ' . $info[5] . ' ' . $info[7]);
    }
}
```

Should get you closer to your goal.

Comment: This won't work if the FTP server is a Windows machine (and hasn't been configured to use Unix formatting, which can be done).  In that event, you'd have to look for the `<dir>` in the listing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the same server, you can do:

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
// set the path to the folder
$path = '/home/user/public_html/my_folder/';
foreach ( $contents as $item ) {
    if ( is_file( $path . $item ) ) {
        echo $item . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

For remote server you can check if file exists [with other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php).