# Check that file exists on different domain without reading it

Tags: php

Is there a better way to check whether a file exists (it is on different domain so file_exists won't work) than this?

```
$fp = fsockopen($fileUri, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    // file exists
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do like this. It work always fine:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
$header_response = get_headers($url, 1);
if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false )
{
  // FILE DOES NOT EXIST
}
else
{
  // FILE EXISTS!!
}
```

Comment: get_headers is slower than curl I think.

Comment: curl libraries ahve proven to be more responsive and faster transferring data then regular php functions, which is why i think that get_headers would be slower. i have no proof, just what i have read in places, forums etc.

Comment: I'd consider changing line 3 to `if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "200" ) === false )` so that 403 access-denied files aren't returned as available.

Answer (score 6):

see this [example](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2008/11/20/php-check-if-file-exists-on-different-domain/) and the explanations

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
$header_response = get_headers($url, 1);
if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false )
{
  // FILE DOES NOT EXIST
} 
else 
{
  // FILE EXISTS!!
}
```

or

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/path/to/image.gif",0,null,0,1);
```

set maxlength to 1

Answer (score 3):

You could use curl and check the headers for a response code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php) has a few examples you could use.

When using curl, use curl_setopt to switch CURLOPT_NOBODY to true so that it only downloads the headers and not the full file. E.g. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);`

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#98128

```
function http_file_exists($url)
{
    $f=@fopen($url,"r");
    if($f)
    {
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

All my tests show that it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I would use curl to check the headers for this and validate the content type.

Something like:

```
function ExternalFileExists($location,$misc_content_type = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init($location);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_exec($curl);

    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

    if((int)$info['http_code'] >= 200 && (int)$info['http_code'] <= 206)
    {
        //Response says ok.
        if($misc_content_type !== false)
        {
             return strpos($info['content_type'],$misc_content_type);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then you can use like so:

```
if(ExternalFileExists('http://server.com/file.avi','video'))
{

}
```

or if your unsure about the extension then like so:

```
if(ExternalFileExists('http://server.com/file.ext'))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used Alexander's solution for now (it's just one place in my app) but in case I need to check for external files in several places in my application I will probably use your function.

Comment: Your best of beuilding a curl library that can send(get/post) recive(headers/html/files) and also interact with `DOMDocument`. This way you have everything you need within 1 lib.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
<?php
      $a = file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/test.html');
      if ($a) echo('exists'); else echo('not exists');
```

Comment: He did say that he does not want the content, but mealy check if it exists, what if the file is a few `GB` ?

Comment: you're right. then it's better to use CURL and setopt to get only headers

Comment: see my answer with using maxlength parameter

Comment: This wouldn't work if the file existed but was 0 bytes in length.