# is URL valid or not

Tags: php, url, url-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [what is the best way to check if a Url exists in PHP ?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437223/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-url-exists-in-php)

I'm looking for a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` in php, either the URL is valid or not.

`isValidURL($url);` I think that simple... That would take into count all kind of URL possible.

By valid I want it to refer to an existing page of the web or other kind of files. It just should exist.

Comment: And valid means what? Syntactically valid? Or references an existing resource?

Comment: @Gordon: That depends on James’ definition of validity.

Comment: hey guys thanks a lot for your help. By valid i want It to referes to an existing page of the web or other kind of files. It just should exist...

Comment: possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+url+exists+php

Comment: A valid url is defined by its RFC http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html

Comment: thanks everyone, sorry for the trouble. you still helped me a lot

Comment: This many or may not be a duplicate, but it is not a duplicate of the question that it is linked to as a duplicate. This question is asking about "valid" URLs, that question is asking about "available" URLS. Entirely possible that a valid URL is not available.

Answer (score 60):

```
<?php

$url = "http://stack*overflow.org";


if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
{
        echo "Not valid";
}else{
        echo "VALID";
}
?>
```

**this does not check *tlds* though**

Comment: this is good one, but your own example is validates to `true` ;) `http://stackoverflow.invalid`. So it's not reliable too ;-)

Comment: @Nemoden: I know it isn't. But I told that already in my post...

Comment: @Nemoden: What's wrong with the URL stackoverflow.invalid? You can setup your own local DNS to handle all sorts of TLD's. I have *.lan pointing to several local development sites behind a firewall. ;)

Comment: Note: this will also allow `http://stackoverflow` with no extension at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow is also a valid url, extentions are not required for valid urls, localhost is a valid url too

Comment: I guess it's a good idea to use this first and than do more reliable but slower check using `get_headers()`.

Comment: Note: neither `http://åäö.se` or even `http://example.com?s=åäö` is considered valid by this method.

Comment: IPv6 addresses are also considered invalid by this method.

Comment: @JonasÄppelgran - Neither `http://åäö.se` nor `http://example.com?s=åäö` are valid URL, though browsers display those characters.Technically, the browser uses punycode to encode domain names and url-encodes parameters. So the correct URLs are `http://xn--4cab6c.se/` and `http://example.com/?s=%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6`

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether URL is valid or not using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function which would return `false` if URL is not valid and an `array` otherwise.

```
function isValidURL($url) { return (bool)parse_url($url); }
```

pretty easy way, huh? :)

Comment: It isn't reliable:http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a4192.php

Comment: Then `preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);` isn't reliable too. But I have my own reason to don't care about domain zone: they will register more domain zones tommorow and I will have to add all of them in all my projects manually? To check if URL is REALLY exists I will use cURL or sockets. For quick check this functions is enough for me. I just propose it to the OP and I don't mind if he will not mark my answer as accepted. I just offer an approach which I use myself. And it's more clean rather than `regex` that's why I like it ;-)

Comment: not reliable? schema is good, you should check if it exists the name with gethostbyname:
function isValidURL($url) { $parts = parse_url($url); if((bool)$parts) { return ($parts['host'] != gethostbyname($parts['host']);} else return false; }

Comment: The docs explicitly say "This function is not meant to validate the given URL"...

Comment: @Kloar, "is not meant" does not mean "it can not".

Comment: yeah, +1 it doesn't really work...

Comment: @Nemoden it also can not though, there are absolutely tons of ways to get invalid urls through parse_url