# Match only "www.example.com" but not "www. some text"

Tags: php, regex

Need regex to match links like `www.example.com` in an `html/text`-string but:

- not match `"www. some text after"`
- not match `"www" only such as "some text before www some text after"`
- not match link with `http`
- must start with white space (`\s`) or not character before such as: `" www.example.com"` or `"www.example.com"`

I tried with:

```
'/(^|\s)(www[^\s].[^<> \n\r \s]+)/iex'
```

but also match `"www. some text after"`

Comment: Can you give a before and after sample?

Comment: doesn't have to be regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806929/is-url-valid-or-not

Comment: Try with text:  "Well, www is strange word but www. is closer to my mind.".  You will see that "www." is matched too, but I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking for

```
/(^|\s)(www[^<>\s]+)/
```

`\s` includes `\n`,`\r`

---

You can also use `(?<=^|\s)(www\.[^<>\s.]+\.[^<>\s.]+)(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Much better, but still match "www. some text after". Don't know why.

Comment: OK. This is working for me, based on your proposal:   (^|\s)(www\.[^<>\s]+)/iex