# file_get_contents() removes XML tags

Tags: php, xml, api, file-get-contents

In the browser the following url http://kulturarvsdata.se/raa/fmi/xml/10028201230001 shows up as a regular XML file. but when I'm using

```
file_get_contents('http://kulturarvsdata.se/raa/fmi/xml/10028201230001');
```

it removes all XML tags and just returns the containing text. Why is this happening and how do I avoid it?

Some response headers:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" 
    [1]=> string(35) "Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2015 20:07:04 GMT" 
    [2]=> string(25) "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1" 
    [3]=> string(43) "Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8" 
    [4]=> string(17) "Connection: close" 
}
```

Comment: I do not think that the headers you list are response headers. Please add the output from `var_dump($http_response_header);` to your question (call it after the `file_get_contents` operation). That should also show additional infos.

Comment: Fixed that was the browser headers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
<?php
/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733997/file-get-contents-removes-xml-tags
 */

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo substr(file_get_contents('http://kulturarvsdata.se/raa/fmi/xml/10028201230001'), 0, 256);
```

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pres:item xmlns:pres="http://kulturarvsdata.se/presentation#"><pres:id>10028201230001</pres:id><pres:entityUri>http://kulturarvsdata.se/raa/fmi/10028201230001</pres:entityUri><pres:type>Kulturlämning</pres:type><pres`

So answer is: Works fine.

You perhaps look at the response in the browser which removes the tags? This at least would be a common mistake some users on Stackoverflow ask about.

Comment: I was able to get your code working, but it does not make sense, other XML calls on the same page is working and adding `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` breaks my page. Note that `file_exists('http://kulturarvsdata.se/raa/fmi/xml/10028201230001')` returns false.

Comment: the header is for debugging purposes (it should perevent the browser from hiding the tags) so sure if you do more with the same script, this influences the whole output and might look broken - `file_exists` on HTTP URLs is not such a good idea, see as well this intersting question about it: [What is the best way to check if a URL exists in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4437223/367456)

Comment: Later in my code I using the result of `file_get_contents()` and add it to a `simpleXMLElement()`: `$xml = file_get_contents($urlQuery);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);` the $xml object is empty...

Comment: You should start with error checking now: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456) - From your response headers things look quite fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

simplexml_load_file — Interprets an XML file into an object

```
<?php
// The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
?>
```

Comment: It fails, I'm guessing that mean that the XML is broken?

Comment: @Abbe: That depends on the concrete error messages. (Edit: XML from that URL is fine, just checked it again.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and I solved it changing the way of fetching the information, so instead of using file_get_contents, I used curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```