# PHP - Determing existence of remote file

Tags: php, file, http-status-code-404

I need to determine if a remote file exists or not.

I have used curl, but it propably reads whole file because it's very slow.

Is there any fast method to "touch" a remote file (for example read only one byte of that file or return false when a 404 occurs)?

Also there could be a problem if tested domain does not exist or connection simply times out. So there has to be timeout interval set to lower than the usual value.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before : Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just want to check the existance of the file, you can use curl to make a `HEAD` Request instead of a `GET`. This way the webserver will only answer with the header information (including the 200/404/... status code) and not the entire file

Comment: ..and if status is 200 it's ok, in case of some 300s code, i will "redirect myself" to new one (for example google.com is moved)....
Thank you ! You saved my time ;-) Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

You have to send HEAD request, in this way only HTTP headers will be returned, and not the whole file

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```