# How to check if the remote server images exist?

Tags: php, remote-access

I am trying to test if the remote images exist before I process my codes..

I have found this post

[How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

I have tried `getimagesize` function and `file_get_contents` function but I got

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /project/testImages.php on line 147
```

I can't modify the server configuration in my case.

I am not sure how to solve the errors or if there are another ways to workaround.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/982045/1729885).

Comment: Why do you need know if this images exist? Because probably your server denies external access.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) with `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to 1 (or `true`)? Then just check the returned contents for server response. That's the way I'd do it.