# PHP file_exists() says existing file does not exist

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if an XML file exists, depending on a username parameter

```
<?php
$username = $_GET["username"];
$filename = "/documents/$username/data.xml";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
   // output documents
} else {
   echo "No documents exist in your account.";
}
?>
```

It continues to return that the file doesn't exist.

**Full path:** http://example.com/documents/{username}/data.xml

*Why does it continue to return false when I know the file exists?*

> EDIT: I made this post years ago, this is definitely not the best way to keep user data, but the answers to this post serve as good explanations of file_exists().

Comment: AFAIK, file_exists does not work for URLs. You have to convert `$filename` to a local path.

Comment: `echo $filename;` and also permissions could be an issue.

Comment: Don't confuse filepaths relative to the webserver root with filesystem filepaths relative to the disk root

Comment: @StrubT you mean instead of `http://example.com/johndoe1/docs.xml`, `/johndoe1/docs.xml?`

Comment: @brandonjordan Yes, exactly. (As others pointed out, you can check remotely by using other functions, but I think when you have the file locally you should test locally as it is easier and probably faster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file_exists()` function is designed for checking a **local** file on the same server as the PHP code.

In common with other file handling functions, it can also read URLs, but this feature can be considered a security risk, and many servers disable it, and restrict you to only reading files from the local server.

You should check whether your server allows you to do this or not. If not, you will have to use a different method to read the remote URL, for example, using CURL.

Please also see the [comments in the `file_exists()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php); one entry explictly gives an answer for how to read a remote file. Here's the code quoted from the manual comment:

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't there not be a @? in `get_headers`

Comment: @brandonjordan - quite right, the probably shouldn't be one there. But as I said, I just copied the code direct from the manual page. My point being less about "here's the code", and more "take a look, the answer is there in the manual already".

Answer (score 3):

**file_exists** checks if a file exists in your local or in a mounted file system of your computer. It cannot check remote files via http.

To test this, you can try getting the file and validate the sent header:

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = get_headers($file);
$exists = ($file_headers[0] != 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

$exists is true when the file exists and false if the file doesnt exist.

Answer (score 3):

`file_exist` check local files. If you want to check files via URL use

`fopen()` - that returns NULL is file has not been opened

or `cURL` (visit: [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php))

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/userdata/johndoe1/docs.xml");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// $retcode > 400 -> not found, $retcode = 200, found.
curl_close($ch);
```