# php how to check a file exists on remote server or not

Tags: php

When I open my Linux terminal and type the following command:

```
rsync server_name.xxx.com:/directory_name
```

It works perfectly, the information of the file is shown on the screen. 
However, when I put the command in a php file like this:

```
$variable='rsync server_name.xxx.com:/directory_name'; 
$output=shell_exec($variable); 
echo $output;
```

Nothing shows up on the browser. Trust me, I have do the Google search for several hours, and find no clue. How can I know if a file locates at another remote server exist   (readable) or not without logging on that server?

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Comment: PHP might be running with different permissions than the user you're logging into the terminal with.

Answer (score 1):

You want the file_exists function. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: @andrewsi, Local files as i know of.

Comment: Remote servers if you are doing it url style, i.e. file_exists('http://192.168.0.1/filename.txt') would work. Otherwise you can check it with ssh/sftp $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$fileExists = file_exists('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/file.txt');

Comment: Yee, most people don't realize file_exists can be used both local and remotely. Here's documentation on using ssh2_sftp though, it's just a matter of using them both in combination http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php