# php advanced redirect using cURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I want to redirect a page to another server using php. But sometimes the server goes down for maintenance as It's still in BETA.

So I would like to use a php script which can first run a curl function or code to receive a particular value from the server to ensure that the server is online. then redirect the page.

like

```
curl http://11.21.21.231/curl_connector_script.php
```

then recive the value as a string

```
if $string=1
```

run the php redirect code

```
else
```

showing in my page that server is offline

Sorry but I am very very new to php.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this in a proper php code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if itsnt ssl, you can use 
$status = file_get_contents('http://server.com/curl_connector_script.php');

This script http://server.com/curl_connector_script.php can returning some flag "1"

Comment: sorry but I am a nob to php could you please explain the code further as it works on php? and what code I should include in the curl_connector_script.php ? should I just put a value there like 1? or something???

Comment: curl_connector_script.php code:
<?php
echo '1';
?>

if this script will return some value, when server ok

Answer (score 0):

This should go on the very top of whatever file you have

```
$resp = file_get_contents('http://11.21.21.231/curl_connector_script.php');
if($resp == 0) { // Not online
    header('location: offline.php');
}
```

This works by sending a simple get request to the page that checks the status of your website, if the response is zero, meaning not online, then he's redirected to offline.php using headers

Comment: and what code I should include the curl_connector_script.php ?

Comment: It depends on how your servers gets into maintenance mode.

Comment: I just need to check if the file is available or not.. if file is available then I will run the redirect code and if not then I will not redirect the page to that server but I will show in my page that the server is offline..