# file_exists() return false for files with whitespaces in the name

Tags: php, file-exists

I have this code:

```
$url     = 'http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /14222-228x228.jpg';
$headers = get_headers($url, true);
var_dump($headers);
```

this returns error for missing file because of the whitespace in the file name:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(34) "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" ["Date"]=>     
string(29) "Tue, 24 Mar 2015 16:11:18 GMT" ["Server"]=> string(6) "Apache" 
["Content-Length"]=> string(3) "677" ["Connection"]=> string(5) "close" 
["Content-Type"]=> string(29) "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" } file size:677
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your spaces probably need urlencoding

Comment: this sounds idea ! let me test

Comment: Then perhaps you need to consider the note in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) "`Tip -
As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality`", and note that [http://](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support `stat()`

Comment: `servImagesDir` should probably be `$servImagesDir`

Comment: no man, this is my config images path.. Problem is in the remote image, not on local server.. Test to see if you can copy this image and than open it..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `file_exists()` is for the file system, not http. You need to use server directory path. If it is on the same server as your code, it should rather look like:

```
if(file_exists('image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg')){
....
```

if on remote server, try:

```
if(file_get_contents('http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg')){
...
```

You can find many other ways here: [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Comment: this is on remote server that I dont have access to it.. How to check for the file in my case?

Comment: Also I am using copy() function to copy the file but it doesnt find the file also

Comment: #CBroe the question now has new dimensions :).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
copy('http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg', '/image.jpeg');
```

if not, use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

```
//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/location/to/save/image.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: #Ahmed, can you please try to copy that image with your method to see you will succeed to copy but the image can not be opened, can you please try?

Comment: i forget to add this , '/image.jpeg' can you try now ?: copy('http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg', '/image.jpeg');

Comment: same thing, did you try it also? Could you see/open the image?

Comment: try with this and show us the error :  copy('http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg', 'image.jpg'); with "http :// www."

Comment: Warning: copy(bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /202441-500x500.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/..../...../root/example2.php on line 18

Comment: But the error is because of the wrong image path.. not related to the fact that image can not be copied successfuly..